# Fetch Olivetti Faces with Proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, scikit-learn, scikits

I am trying to fetch Olivetti faces from the sklearn dataset but I get an URLError. I know the error is because usually I need to go through a proxy for any outside request.

In this case I don't see an option to declare a proxy url for the fetch_olivetti_faces() method. Any suggestions on how to execute this request through a proxy?

```
from sklearn import datasets
olivetti = datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like with the `Enthought Canopy` Editor you can setup a proxy under `Edit > Preferences` and select the option to `Pass these proxy settings to terminal and ipython: Yes`

**Note:** For me the changes took effect after i did a Kernel under restart `Run > Kernel Restart`